# Will Questions asked by Anonymous Users get Accepted Answer Status?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, community-user, anonymous

This question also includes the questions owned by the Community User (incase the user who first asked the question deletes the account).

Can the anonymous user accept an answer to his/her question?

Comment: @random so anonymous questions never get any accepted status answers?

Comment: Deleted, no. Anonymous, that's another account type entirely